# Static object references and non static object references in Java

Tags: java, class, static

What is the difference between the static object references and the non-static object references?

```
public class Example {
    int r =10;
    void output() {
        System.out.println("The value is "+r++);
    }
}

public class Test {
    static Example q,w,e;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        q = new Example();    
        q.output();
        w = new Example();
        w.output();
        e = new Example();
        e.output();

        example r,t,y;
        r = new Example();
        r.output();

        t = new Example();
        t.output();

        y = new Example();
        y.output();
    }
}
```

While running this code the output of this code is same.
So the questions arises that:

- What is the use of declaring a static reference variable in code, and
- What is the difference between these static and non-static reference variable in Java.

Comment: duh... the output is gonna be always same... because different static objects are accessing non-static variable of a class...

Comment: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/10/15/static-variables-java/

Answer (score 1):

A static variable is shared within all instances of a class and will always remain the same, a non static variable is specific to a single instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable can be accessed from other methods of the same class, or even from other classes (if it's public). The non static variables in your code a local variables, and they are only accessible to the `main` method, in which they are declared.

The output is the same since you call your `output` method each time for a difference instance of the `example` class. In each of them `r` is initialized to `10`, so `r++` returns `10`.

Answer (score 0):

This objects are bonded with class level. It will create the example q, w, e when your class loaded. Then objects will be assigned to p, q, w when you run the method. Then you can access that objects with class reference.

```
example.q or example.getq() //need to create getq static method
```

without creating Test object.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating object of one class into another so which type of object you're creating will not affect to the value of instance. The JVM always return the same type of object with its instances.